# Adding Javascript events to SVG <def> elements instead of directly on the children?

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I know that it is possible to attach plain-old Javascript event handlers to elements within an SVG tag.  I am looking to duplicate very many instances of an object, so I am planning to use the `<def>` and `<use>` tags to simplify things a bit.    However each of my children  items will need to handle "click" and other events.  I could define those events for each child, but it would be nice if I could somehow define them ONCE in the initial  items, and then just "reuse" that click event.  Is this possible?

https://jsfiddle.net/khyp1o0w/

```
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
    <defs>
        <rect id="someDef" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="30" fill="#f00" />  
        <!--  ^^ would like to define an event here... -->
    </defs>

    <use x="150" y="150" xlink:href="#someDef" />
    <use x="250" y="250" xlink:href="#someDef" />  
    <!--  ^^  ... that is used by these guys  -->

</svg>
```

EDIT: Adding example SVG.

Comment: That's what we call [event delegation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/2813224) but instead of registering event on children, you register on parent.

Comment: @zer00ne: I'm aware of event delegation.  I'm trying to use this in an SVG element on a <def> tag, and have it apply to the <use> tags which reference it.  Regular event delegation does not seem to apply here, since the <use> tags are not truly children of the <def> tag which they reference.

Comment: Like I have no idea what you have so provide a [mcve] and perhaps we can see if event delegation is possible.

Comment: @zer00ne:  I went ahead and added a minimal example.  I really didn't think one was necessary, since I'm just asking a straightforward question about <use> tags...  :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC elements targeted by a `use` element should be internally copied into the `<use>` element just like if the `<use>` were an iframe, and the content were cloned.

So this means that events attached on the original node won't be copied onto the copies, **unless this event is part of the node markup** (inlined). But chrome don't really follow specs here and won't even make it work... So here is an example for FF :

```js
// this won't work
document.getElementById('someDef').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.setAttribute('stroke', randomColor());
});
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <defs>
    <script type="application/javascript">
      function randomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
          color += letters[~~(Math.random() * 15)];
        }
        return color;
      }
    </script>
    <!-- this will work in FF -->
    <rect id="someDef" onclick="this.setAttribute('fill',randomColor())" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="30" fill="#f00" />
  </defs>

  <use x="150" y="150" xlink:href="#someDef" />
  <use x="250" y="250" xlink:href="#someDef" />
</svg>
```

You could of course use event delegation by listening for click events on your root svg element, but this would work only for direct target elements, not for nested ones :

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
svg.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var usedTargetID = e.target.getAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", 'href');
  switch (usedTargetID) {
    case '#direct':
      clickDirect(e);
      break;
    case '#nested':
      clickNested(e);
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }
});

function clickDirect(e) {
  // what you seem to want
  e.target.setAttribute('fill', randomColor());
}

function clickNested(e) {
  // will set both nested...
  e.target.setAttribute('fill', randomColor());
}

function randomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[~~(Math.random() * 15)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <defs>
    <rect id="direct" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="30" />
    <g id="nested">
      <!-- you can only access this -->
      <!-- not its content individually -->
      <rect x="80" y="0" width="60" height="30" />
      <rect x="20" y="70" width="60" height="30" />
    </g>

  </defs>

  <use x="150" y="50" xlink:href="#direct" />
  <use x="250" y="150" xlink:href="#nested" />
</svg>
```

Or you could also add an event per element, but this would have the same limitations as delegation...